# how to setup a OneDrive folder as a git repo?

Tags: php, git, github, onedrive

I created a folder on OneDrive called My files>GitHub>MedAverter.  I note it's url:

> https://onedrive.live.com/?id=CC97284F14BADC27%211034825&cid=CC97284F14BADC27

I downloaded GitHub Desktop and set the Current repository to the newly created MedAverter folder.

I navigate to my local code folder in git bash:
/c/users/greg/LaravelProjects/MedAverter

I enter the following command:

```
git remote set-url origin https://onedrive.live.com/?id=CC97284F14BADC27%211034824&cid=CC97284F14BADC27
```

To check it is correct, I do:

```
git remote -v
```

here is the output:

```
origin  https://onedrive.live.com/?id=CC97284F14BADC27%211034824 (fetch)  
origin  https://onedrive.live.com/?id=CC97284F14BADC27%211034824 (push)
```

Note that it is shorter than the original?

I do a git status and see a bunch of unstaged files, as expected.  I stage them with

```
git add .
```

Then I commit the files with:

```
git commit -m "first commit"
```

Then push the files with:

```
git push -u origin master
```

But get error:

> fatal:
>   https://onedrive.live.com/?id=CC97284F14BADC27%211034824/info/refs not
>   valid: is this a git repository?

What am I missing?

Comment: I gave up on using OneDrive as a source control repo for git.  Used BitBucket instead.  Trying to push to there gives a new error "error: failed to push some refs to 'https://tekknow@bitbucket.org/tekknow/medaverter.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do
hint: not have locally. This is usually caused by another repository pushing
hint: to the same ref. You may want to first integrate the remote changes
hint: (e.g., 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details."

Comment: so I did a pull and then a push but got the same error

Comment: finally got it to work by adding the --force option, as in git push -u --force origin master

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to use an HTTP remote for Git, it either has to support the smart protocol, which requires a special server endpoint, or it has to support WebDAV, which is commonly referred to as the dumb protocol.  In addition, the remote cannot use query parameters, since Git will not handle them.

If you want to use OneDrive with WebDAV, you'll need some way to get the initial repository structure up to the server, which will likely involve using a standard WebDAV client to upload a directory created with `git init --bare`.

As mentioned, you'll also need a WebDAV URL that doesn't include any query parameters; if OneDrive can't provide that, then you'd need to use a different provider.

Do note that you should not use OneDrive as a syncing tool for your Git repository across machines because doing so can cause corruption.

Comment: I'll assume you are right but sounds too complicated and too much work so I'm not going to pursue it any further since I got it working with BitBucket instead.  Hopefully others will benefit from your solution.  Here are some other links I discovered that might be helpful to others: https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/create-a-git-repository-759857290.html, https://bruceoutdoors.wordpress.com/2014/01/25/automatic-deployment-workflow-with-bitbucketgit-in-hostgator/, https://www.5balloons.info/hosting-laravel-5-5-project-on-shared-hosting-hostgator/

Answer (score 2):

I **strongly** suggest that you do not use OneDrive shared folders to host a git repository you are working on locally whether you are syncing across machines or not.

One Drive has some challenges keeping a proper sync when files are deleted, and this can cause havoc on your working directory.

As of October 2022, this issue has not been resolved and I've been burned by it in the past.

Example:
Refactoring your code (or changing branches/commits) can result in files that need to be removed from your project. OneDrive doesn't always recognize the local file deletions and so it will synchronize the files back and whole folders/files can re-appear whenever this happens.

The working directly may then be polluted with folder/file additions that you did not intend and can cause havoc.

Bottom Line: Git is the tool to manage your working directory related to repo and collaboration. Backups need to be managed with the git repository stores itself, and do yourself a favour and don't mix OneDrive and Local repos or working directories

Here is a link with a "fix" that isn't a fix for this use case but explains the issue in better detail for reference:
https://www.urtech.ca/2021/01/solved-files-synced-to-onedrive-keep-reappearing-after-deletion/