# Can SharePoint be used for mercurial repositories?

Tags: sharepoint, mercurial

Can I use a SharePoint folder to  store a mercurial repository?  I've read OneDrive [may not be a good option for git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60791844/how-to-setup-a-onedrive-folder-as-a-git-repo#60794224) (also [here](https://www.dustinbriles.com/onedrive-and-git-dont-do-it/)) but I have not seen anything specific (either pro or con) to SharePoint and hg.  I'd like to use SharePoint because it's already available to me and it will allow the entire team to access the repository.

Comment: Since the Mercurial repository (the .hg folder) is made up of many files all of which would have to be synchronized together, I doubt sharepoint would work well. Probably the same issues git would face.  There are other simple ways to share an HG repo, like `hg serve` however.

Comment: Thx!  If sync is turned off on the sharepoint and it's then mapped like a network drive could this resolve any issues?

Comment: I doubt it. If every file in .hg is not synced when you use it I think it may corrupt the repo.